# Getting error while capturing payment in RazorPay. Undefined index, razorpay_signature

Tags: php, razorpay

I've integrated Razorpay payments using PHP, and I'm getting error while capturing the payment, with the following errors.

```
Notice: Undefined index: razorpay_signature in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/feedback/dashboard/admin/verify.php on line 27

Warning: hash_equals(): Expected user_string to be a string, null given in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/feedback/dashboard/admin/razorpay-php/src/Utility.php on line 32
```

Screenshot:

> Undefined index: Razorpay Signature

[image]
*Note: Amount generated for paying is dynamic in my case!*

Comment: How can I reslove the error? If I try to make payments using razor pay sample php test app, I'm able to capture the payment successfully, but when I integrate it in my project I'm not able to capture! @Daan

Comment: Are you using automatic or manual checkout?

Comment: Automatic checkout @Nemo

Comment: Can you check what all changes have you made to automatic.php compared to the same application? Paste it as part of your question?

Answer (score 0):

https://api.razorpay.com/v1/payments/:id/capture

```
{
    "id": "pay_7IZD7aJ2kkmOjk",
    "entity": "payment",
    "amount": 50000,
    "currency": "INR",
    "status": "captured",
    "order_id": null,
    "invoice_id": null,
    "international": false,
    "method": "wallet",
    "amount_refunded": 0,
    "refund_status": null,
    "captured": true,
    "description": "Purchase Description",
    "card_id": null,
    "bank": null,
    "wallet": "freecharge",
    "vpa": null,
    "email": "a@b.com",
    "contact": "91xxxxxxxx",
    "notes": {
        "merchant_order_id": "order id"
    },
    "fee": 1438,
    "tax": 188,
    "error_code": null,
    "error_description": null,
    "created_at": 1400826750
}
```

https://api.razorpay.com/v1/payments/pay_29QQoUBi66xm2f/capture

Answer (score -1):

https://api.razorpay.com/v1/payments/:id/capture

```
 - {
       "id": "pay_7IZD7aJ2kkmOjk",
       "entity": "payment",
       "amount": 50000,
       "currency": "INR",
       "status": "captured",
       "order_id": null,
       "invoice_id": null,
       "international": false,
       "method": "wallet",
       "amount_refunded": 0,
       "refund_status": null,
       "captured": true,
       "description": "Purchase Description",
       "card_id": null,
       "bank": null,
       "wallet": "freecharge",
       "vpa": null,
       "email": "a@b.com",
       "contact": "91xxxxxxxx",
       "notes": {
           "merchant_order_id": "order id"
       },
       "fee": 1438,
       "tax": 188,
       "error_code": null,
       "error_description": null,
       "created_at": 1400826750 }
```

https://api.razorpay.com/v1/payments/pay_29QQoUBi66xm2f/capture

Comment: You should explain how OP could resolve the issue with this