# How to fix razorpay payment integration "Razorpay_signature" returning undefined?

Tags: javascript, php, payment, gateway, razorpay

I have integrated razor pay payment gateway into my site, which captures payment without any error, but after capturing it returns with paymentId and OrderId but not with signature which leads to webhook not being hit from razor pay end and payment status returning to failure.

I have tried many ways but none resulted in positive.

**Here's my code :**

Payment Page :

```
require('payment/config.php');
                            require('payment/razorpay-php/Razorpay.php');

                            // Create the Razorpay Order
                            
                            use Razorpay\Api\Api;
                            
                            $api = new Api($keyId, $keySecret);

  if($count > 100000) { } else {
      
                            //
                            // We create an razorpay order using orders api
                            // Docs: https://docs.razorpay.com/docs/orders
                            //
                            $orderData = [
                                'receipt'         => $o_id,
                                'amount'          => $count * 100,
                                'currency'        => 'INR',
                                'payment_capture' => 1 // auto capture
                            ];
                            
                            $razorpayOrder = $api->order->create($orderData);
                            
                            $razorpayOrderId = $razorpayOrder['id'];
                            
                            $_SESSION['razorpay_order_id'] = $razorpayOrderId;
                            
                            $displayAmount = $amount = $orderData['amount'];
                            
                            if ($displayCurrency !== 'INR')
                            {
                                $url = "https://api.fixer.io/latest?symbols=$displayCurrency&base=INR";
                                $exchange = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);
                            
                                $displayAmount = $exchange['rates'][$displayCurrency] * $amount / 100;
                            }
                            
                            $checkout = 'automatic';
                            
                            if (isset($_GET['checkout']) and in_array($_GET['checkout'], ['automatic', 'manual'], true))
                            {
                                $checkout = $_GET['checkout'];
                            }
                            
                            $data = [
                                "key"               => $keyId,
                                "amount"            => $amount,
                                "o_id"              => $o_id,
                                "name"              => 'VDOfy',
                                "description"       => 'Videos',
                                "image"             => "https://vdofy.com/images/others/vdofy-mini.png",
                                "prefill"           => [
                                "email"             => $email,
                                "contact"           => $mobile,
                                ],
                                "notes"             => [
                                "merchant_order_id" => $o_id,
                                ],
                                "theme"             => [
                                "color"             => "#F37254"
                                ],
                                "order_id"          => $razorpayOrderId,
                            ];
                            
                            if ($displayCurrency !== 'INR')
                            {
                                $data['display_currency']  = $displayCurrency;
                                $data['display_amount']    = $displayAmount;
                            }
                            
                            $json = json_encode($data);

}
```

**Checkout Automatic.php**

```
<form action="verify.php" method="POST" >
  <script
    src="https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/checkout.js"
    data-key="<?php echo $data['key']?>"
    data-amount="<?php echo $data['amount']?>"
    data-currency="INR"
    data-name="<?php echo $data['name']?>"
    data-image="<?php echo $data['image']?>"
    data-description="<?php echo $data['description']?>"
    data-prefill.name="<?php echo $data['prefill']['name']?>"
    data-prefill.email="<?php echo $data['prefill']['email']?>"
    data-prefill.contact="<?php echo $data['prefill']['contact']?>"
    data-notes.shopping_order_id="<?php echo $data['o_id']?>"
    data-order_id="<?php echo $data['order_id']?>"
    
    <?php if ($displayCurrency !== 'INR') { ?> data-display_amount="<?php echo $data['display_amount']?>" <?php } ?>
    <?php if ($displayCurrency !== 'INR') { ?> data-display_currency="<?php echo $data['display_currency']?>" <?php } ?>
  >
  </script>
    
  <input type="hidden" name="shopping_order_id" value="<?php echo $data['o_id']?>">
</form>
```

**Verify.php**

```
<?php

require('payment/config.php');

session_start();

require('payment/razorpay-php/Razorpay.php');
use Razorpay\Api\Api;
use Razorpay\Api\Errors\SignatureVerificationError;

$success = true;

$error = "Payment Failed";

if (empty($_POST['razorpay_payment_id']) === false)
{
    $api = new Api($keyId, $keySecret);

    try
    {
        // Please note that the razorpay order ID must
        // come from a trusted source (session here, but
        // could be database or something else)
        $attributes = array(
            'razorpay_order_id' => $_SESSION['razorpay_order_id'],
            'razorpay_payment_id' => $_POST['razorpay_payment_id'],
            'razorpay_signature' => $_POST['razorpay_signature']
        );

        $api->utility->verifyPaymentSignature($attributes);
    }
    catch(SignatureVerificationError $e)
    {
        $success = false;
        $error = 'Razorpay Error : ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
}

if ($success === true)
{
    
  header("location:updatequote"); 
}
else
{
    $html = "<p>Your payment failed</p>
             <p>{$error} - {$_POST['razorpay_payment_id']} - {$_SESSION['razorpay_order_id']} - {$_POST['razorpay_signature']}</p>";
}

echo $html;
```

In verify.php it returns to failure as payment signature is passed null or undefined. But when checked both razorpay_order_id and razorpay_payment_id are returned properly. And because of this, my webhook link couldn't get any data as response from razorpay.

I even tried browsing in stack but got none related to my issus, except [this...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46772092/getting-error-while-capturing-payment-in-razorpay-undefined-index-razorpay-sig)  which isn't helpfull.

This is the error i'm getting :
[image: This is the error i'm getting]

Any help is greatly appreciated.